# Question about Harvey's quote

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, quotations

"Nothing  that  happens on the surface of the sea can alter the calm of its depths"

Whenever I see this quote,I always enter into an ambiguity, I tend to interpret that quote with two different meanings.

1)Things that happens on the surface of the sea,doesn't affect its calmness.

2)If the surface of the sea is being silent( which means nothings happen over there) can affect the calmness of its depth.

Can anyone say which one is correct...

Comment: Are you looking for a scientific or a English meaning?

Comment: @gandalf-English meaning, i belive this site is not the right place to seek scientific meanings?

Answer (score 1):

Googling this, I find that it is a quote from *Andrew Harvey, The Direct Path: Creating a Personal Journey to the Divine Using the World's Spirtual Traditions*.  In a context such as this, it's a metaphor for life.  A hurricane on the surface of the sea doesn't create any disturbance a mile down.  In the same way, none of life's adversities can alter the spiritual core of who we are.